# OpenVPN generating a ton of traffic

Tags: openvpn

I have a fresh instalatio of an Ubuntu 16.10 and I have installed OpenVPN following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I was able to make everything work after installing. The only problem that I'm facing right now is this:

```
22:44:38.473959 IP bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279 > ID11584.ssh: Flags [.], ack 490928, win 253, length 0
    22:44:38.473968 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 516672:516912, ack 321, win 519, length 240
    22:44:38.474722 IP bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279 > ID11584.ssh: Flags [.], ack 491520, win 250, length 0
    22:44:38.474731 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 516912:517264, ack 321, win 519, length 352
    22:44:38.474953 IP bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279 > ID11584.ssh: Flags [.], ack 492112, win 256, length 0
    22:44:38.474962 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 517264:517616, ack 321, win 519, length 352
    22:44:38.475224 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 517616:517968, ack 321, win 519, length 352
    22:44:38.476016 IP bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279 > ID11584.ssh: Flags [.], ack 493232, win 252, length 0
    22:44:38.476026 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 517968:518208, ack 321, win 519, length 240
    22:44:38.476017 IP bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279 > ID11584.ssh: Flags [.], ack 493664, win 256, length 0
    22:44:38.476340 IP ID11584.ssh > bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279: Flags [P.], seq 518208:518736, ack 321, win 519, length 528
```

After a `tcpdump -i eth0` I have found that there is a lot of traffic going around in my server. The `bl19-108-61.dsl.telepac.pt.54279` is an IP that I know but the VPN is turned off in this IP. I'm talking about 20 requests per second. I have checked the config file but everything seems to be the way the tutorial taught.

Is this normal? This amount of traffic is normal to generate after setting up a VPN server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the port: "**.ssh**".
The packets are from SSH remote shell, nothing to do with VPN.

If this is your local IP, it may even be the shell you are using to run the tcpdump.

To prevent this, always add " and not port 22" at the end of your tcpdump command, if you are not dumping a different IP than then one you are using to connect.

Comment: This is weird because at other servers that I had I had to analyze some traffic while logged at SSH but it never got this amount of packets from SSH.

Comment: Maybe someone behind this IP is also working on the same server as you.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm the only one logged in.

Comment: So if this is your IP, it's definitely your own ssh client!